# Finding the intersection of two piecewise linear function

Tags: c++

I have a two piecewise linear functions, one increasing, one decreasing. 
Each of the functions is expressed as two arrays of doubles. These are coordinates of the functions.

One function can be (1,2,3) (10,20,30). Another function can be expressed as an array of doubles (1.5, 2.5, 3.2) (30, 20, 15). I need to write a c++ function to work out the interception points of these two monotonic, piecewise linear functions. In this case, the answer is 2.25

I have not came up with an efficient algorithm yet. Any ideas?

The way I came up with so far is to work through the domain. increasing the x-axis for 1 function, and solve per pair, but this seems to be a brute force method. is there way of solving this quicker using monotonicity.

Comment: Please show us what you got so far in an [mcve]. Your question needs more clarification. How do you express the functions with the two arrays? Are they coordinates?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question but a math question.  Use two points from each set to calculate `mx+b` and then solve both linear equations for their intersection.

Comment: If you have two lines y1 = m1*x1 + b1 and y2 = m2*x2 + b2 you can set them equal to each other and solve for the common point.  If they intersect you'll find one solution; if they don't there won't be a solution.  You don't need an "algorithm", just enough knowledge to solve two equations for two unknowns.

Comment: @duffymo because one of the piecewise linear function is increasing, the other one is decreasing. there ought be a more efficient alogrithm.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?  Nothing more efficient than my suggestion.

Comment: This is efficient.  It is O(1) to calculate the intersection of two lines.

Comment: @duffymo do you understand the question? i have two piecewise linear functions, not two linear functions. not to be rude, but i do have a maths PhD...

Comment: I have a Ph.D. in mechanical engineering.  I know how to solve two simultaneous equations - I learned how in high school.  You'd have to check every pair of piecewise contributions to the two functions to find an intersection.  It's symmetric, since the intersection of f1 and f2 is the same as f2 and f1.  You can exit the loop as soon as you find one. Feels like a piecewise root finder.

Comment: seems brute-forcey (and yes i know how to do that)

Comment: You don't need to take all pairwise combinations of segments, just the overlapping ones.  Start with the first segment on each polyline, then consider the next vertex of each.  Whichever vertex has the lower `x` value, advance that polyline to the next segment.  If your polylines have `k1` and `k2` segments, respectivement, this is `O(k1 + k2)` not `O(k1 * k2)` as it would be to test all pairs.

Comment: A related algorithm is a merge-sort, you might look for an explanation on that to help you visualize the process.

Comment: @BenVoigt i tried this also, this algorithm has the problem. if the domain is  (1,2) for the first function and (1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,..., 1.9) for the second function, you are in trouble. unless i misunderstood something.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about brute force or elegance.  Make it work, make it work right, make it work fast.

Comment: @Lost1: You only move forward a segment along one of the two polylines at each step.  And you look at the ordinate to decide which one you move along.  Only when both polylines have a breakpoint at the same ordinate will both advance together.

Comment: @fjardon: "Take all the segments from both functions, merge all of them together" is already the same complexity as my entire solution.  The great complexity of binary search doesn't help you if your preprocessing step has worse complexity.

Comment: @BenVoigt indeed you're right it doesn't change the complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the intersecting segments in O(logn<sup>2</sup>) by binary search.

Start with the increasing function F = {f<sub>1</sub>, f<sub>2</sub>,... f<sub>m</sub>} and the decreasing function G = {g<sub>1</sub>, g<sub>2</sub>, ... g<sub>n</sub>}. Pick a point f<sub>k</sub> somewhere in the middle of F, and do a binary search in G for the segment {g<sub>s</sub>, g<sub>s+1</sub>} that contains f<sub>k</sub> in x.

If f<sub>k</sub> is below that segment, then the intersection is to the right and the problem reduces to [{f<sub>k</sub> ... f<sub>m</sub>}, {g<sub>s</sub> ... <sub>n</sub>}]. On the other hand if f<sub>k</sub> is above that segment then the intersection is to the left and the problem reduces to [{f<sub>1</sub> ... f<sub>k</sub>}, {g<sub>1</sub> ... g<sub>s+1</sub>}].

This is a binary search within a binary search, so it works out to O(logn<sup>2</sup>). Determining whether a point is above or below a segment is O(1), and finding the intersection of two segments (once you find them) is O(1).

Comment: {gs, gs+1} may not necessarily exist, for example consider the segment for f covers (1,2), but the segment for g are length of 0.1 as an extreme example.. Hence it is not clear to me what you mean  {gs, gs+1} contains f_k

Comment: @Lost1: fk is a point, not a segment. If I have misunderstood you, please give a complete counterexample.

Comment: do you mean O(log m * log n)?